# Finding all the pathways from vertex s to vertex t

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose that we have a complete graph with `n=5` vertices:

```
vertexset={1,2,3,4,5}
```

We want to identify the set of all the paths (acyclic), for example, from 1 to 4: 
`1->2->3>4` or `1->3->4` or `1->4` etc. Needless to say, for small `n`, the paths can be manually identified. 
I have a large `n` and my graph is not complete. So, the question is: how one can identify all the (acyclic) paths from `s` to `t` in a directed graph.

Comment: `FindPath[g, s, t, Infinity, All]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll: Thanks for your answer. It works for me. I hope you would not mind if I have a follow question. Therefore, I edited my question to formulate the main question. Thanks again.

Comment: @CarlWoll:  I will post a separate question not to confuse others with my previous question.